Unable to disable android component in Android 14
I'm trying to disable an Android component from my system app's service class using the code below. It's working fine in A13 and earlier versions, but it is not disabling the component in A14.
I also added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/> in manifest, but am still facing the same issue. Are there any specific changes required for A14? I checked the documentation but couldn't find relevant changes. I also tried setting targetSdkVersion to 34 and 33, but it didn't resolve the issue and getting exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity does not exist in android.
ComponentName appChooser = new ComponentName(
                "android",
                "com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity");

mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(appChooser, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


It seems the path for ChooserActivity has changed in Android 14. Updating the component details as shown below fixed my issue.
ComponentName appChooser = new ComponentName(
                                        "com.android.intentresolver",
                                        "com.android.intentresolver.chooser.ChooserActivity");
mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(appChooser,
                                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

